# Passing a parameter in <p:commandLink>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I have a code like:

```
<p:commandLink value="#{user.strUserid}" action="test.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

How can I pass a parameter to test.xhtml to get the value in the said page?
I tried with `<f:param>` tag.But can get the value in the `test.xhtml` page.
Please suggest.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: `But can get the value in the test.xhtml page` ... what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 9):

Replace it by `<h:link>`

```
<h:link value="#{user.strUserid}" outcome="test.xhtml">
    <f:param name="foo" value="bar" />
</h:link>
```

and use `<f:viewParam>` to set it as a property of the bean associated with target page

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)

Answer (score 5):

Then I think you need to try `<f:setPropertyActionListener ..`

```
<h:commandButton action="#{testBean.takeParam}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.myStringVal}" value="something" />
</h:commandButton>
```

And then You can get this value in your bean class

```
    @SessionScoped
    public class TestBean{

        public String myStringVal;

        public void setMyStringVal(String myStringVal) {
            this.myStringVal = myStringVal;
        }

    }

    public void takeParam{
         System.out.println("String Value: "+myStringVal);
    }
```

Also see [Communication in JSF by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html)

Comment: OP is using JSF2. That article is targeted on JSF1. There's a JSF2 variant: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html